How to keep the same colors in ggplot for a reordered factor in R
I am making a boxplot but need to reorder the levels for a factor in the data. This factor will be used in ggplot to reflect the levels through three different colors. But when the levels of the factor are reordered, the colors are changed at the same time, which is not something I wish for. The reproducible code is as follows,
x1 <- runif(100)
x2 <- c(rep("c", 30), rep("a", 40), rep("b", 30))
x3 <- rep(seq(0,9), 10)
mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1, x2, x3))

mydata$x4 <- factor(mydata$x2, levels = c("a", "b", "c"), ordered = TRUE)

mydata$x1 <- as.numeric(mydata$x1)
mydata$x2 <- as.factor(mydata$x2)
mydata$x3 <- as.factor(mydata$x3)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x3, y = x1, fill = x2)) +
 geom_boxplot() + 
 labs(x = "x3", y = "x1") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
       legend.position = "top") 

This gives me the boxplots in these three colors

But if I change x2 to x4 (reordered factor), the colors become different!
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x3, y = x1, fill = x4)) +
 geom_boxplot() + 
 labs(x = "x3", y = "x1") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
       legend.position = "top") 


I still want to keep the colors in the first graph for the reordered factor, the same color and same order of colors (first: red, second: green, third: blue). Is there a way for me to keep the same colors for a reordered factor?

You don't have to use ordered = TRUE when changing the order of the levels, by the way, which also avoids this issue entirely.

The issue is that by default ggplot2 will use scale_fill_ordinal in case of an ordered factor (with option ordered=TRUE) which defaults to a viridis color palette, whereas for an unordered factor it will default to scale_fill_discrete which uses a hue color palette.
One option to fix that would be to force a hue fill color scale explicitly using either scale_fill_discrete or scale_fill_hue:
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x3, y = x1, fill = x4)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_discrete() + # or scale_fill_hue
  labs(x = "x3", y = "x1") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 12),
    legend.position = "top"
  )



It works! Thanks!
